# Pure JavaScript infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, observer-pattern

I have a 4 list of posts. I am trying to load more posts (clones of the "original" ones) when I reach the bottom of the container.

```js
class InfiniteScroll {
  constructor() {
    this.observer = null;
    this.isLoading = false;
    this.postsContainer = document.querySelector('#postsContainer');
    this.postsArary = postsContainer.querySelectorAll('.post');
    this.iterationCount = Number(this.postsContainer.dataset.currentPage);
    this.perPage = 5;
    this.maxCount = this.postsContainer?.dataset?.maxCount;
    this.numberOfPages = Math.ceil(this.maxCount / this.perPage);
    this.hasNextPage = this.iterationCount < this.numberOfPages;
  }

  loadMorePosts() {
    if (this.hasNextPage) {
      this.postsArary.forEach(item => {
        let postClone = item.cloneNode(true);
        this.postsContainer.appendChild(postClone);
      });
    } else {
      if (this.observer) this.observer.disconnect();
    }
  }

  getLastPost() {
    const allPosts = postsContainer.querySelectorAll('.post');
    return allPosts[allPosts.length - 1];
  }

  counter() {
    if (this.hasNextPage) {
      this.iterationCount = this.iterationCount + 1;
      this.postsContainer.dataset.currentPage = this.iterationCount;
    }

    this.postsContainer.dataset.hasNextPage = this.hasNextPage;
    this.hasNextPage = this.iterationCount < this.numberOfPages - 1;
  }

  bindLoadMoreObserver() {
    if (this.postsContainer) {
      this.observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
        entries.forEach(entry => {
          if (entry && entry.isIntersecting) {
            observer.unobserve(entry.target);
            this.loadMorePosts();
            this.counter();
            if (this.hasNextPage) {
              observer.observe(this.getLastPost());
            }
          }
        });
      });

      this.observer.observe(this.getLastPost());
    }
  }

  init() {
    this.bindLoadMoreObserver();
  }
}

const infiniteScroll = new InfiniteScroll();
infiniteScroll.init();
```

```css
body, body * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.post {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

p {
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<div id="postsContainer" data-has-next-page="true" data-current-page="0" data-max-count="11">
  <div class="post">
    <h2>Title 1</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque dolorum consequatur nostrum sapiente ipsa! Veniam, laudantium accusantium, odio maxime quo adipisci possimus enim quam, voluptate quidem animi perferendis delectus aliquam?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="post">
    <h2>Title 2</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque dolorum consequatur nostrum sapiente ipsa! Veniam, laudantium accusantium, odio maxime quo adipisci possimus enim quam, voluptate quidem animi perferendis delectus aliquam?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="post">
    <h2>Title 3</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque dolorum consequatur nostrum sapiente ipsa! Veniam, laudantium accusantium, odio maxime quo adipisci possimus enim quam, voluptate quidem animi perferendis delectus aliquam?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="post">
    <h2>Title 4</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque dolorum consequatur nostrum sapiente ipsa! Veniam, laudantium accusantium, odio maxime quo adipisci possimus enim quam, voluptate quidem animi perferendis delectus aliquam?</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Too complex

Always strive to keep source code complexity as low as possible.

The implementation of `InfiniteScroll` is way too complex.

It should not be an instantiatable object as it only works if there is one instance, and will only work once.

- Page counting need only one variable not 3    `this.maxCount`, `this.numberOfPages` and `this.hasNextPage` can be replace with a single counter. See rewrite `pageCount` which counts down.
- There is no need to store `iterationCount` or `hasNextPage` in markup. `this.postsContainer.dataset.currentPage = this.iterationCount;`
- Use Pseudo-class `":last-child"` to select last post. `querySelector(".post:last-child")`
- In function `getLastPost` you reference an undefined variable `const allPosts = postsContainer.querySelectorAll(".post");`  should be `const allPosts = this.postsContainer.querySelectorAll(".post");`
- The second argument of the `IntersectionObserver` is a reference to the same object you already have a reference to, there is no need to use the second argument.
- When the observer callback is called there will only be one entry that you need to handle. Rather than `entries.forEach` use `entries.find` to locate the entry.

### Rewrite

The rewrite does not create an object. The function InfiniteScroll holds the observer. When `observer.disconnect()` is called the `IntersectionObserver` callback will be de-referenced and the closure containing the `InfiniteScroll` will be cleaned up automatically.

To prevent `InfiniteScroll` from being called again it is de-referenced on the first call.

It works the same but with over 65% less code

```js
function InfiniteScroll() {
    InfiniteScroll = undefined;
    const query = (qStr, root = document) => root.querySelector(qStr);
    const lastPost = () => query(".post:last-child", container);

    const perPage = 5;
    const container = query("#postsContainer");
    const posts = container.querySelectorAll(".post");
    var pageCount = container.dataset.maxCount / perPage | 0;

    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(intersect);
    observer.observe(lastPost()); 

    function intersect(entries) {
        const intersecting = entries.find(entry => entry.isIntersecting);
        if (intersecting) {
            observer.unobserve(intersecting.target);
            posts.forEach(item => container.appendChild(item.cloneNode(true))); 
            --pageCount ? observer.observe(lastPost()) : observer.disconnect();
        }
    }
}

InfiniteScroll();
```

```css
body, body * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.post {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

p {
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<div id="postsContainer" data-has-next-page="true" data-current-page="0" data-max-count="11">
  <div class="post">
    <h2>Title 1</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque dolorum consequatur nostrum sapiente ipsa! Veniam, laudantium accusantium, odio maxime quo adipisci possimus enim quam, voluptate quidem animi perferendis delectus aliquam?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="post">
    <h2>Title 2</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque dolorum consequatur nostrum sapiente ipsa! Veniam, laudantium accusantium, odio maxime quo adipisci possimus enim quam, voluptate quidem animi perferendis delectus aliquam?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="post">
    <h2>Title 3</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque dolorum consequatur nostrum sapiente ipsa! Veniam, laudantium accusantium, odio maxime quo adipisci possimus enim quam, voluptate quidem animi perferendis delectus aliquam?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="post">
    <h2>Title 4</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque dolorum consequatur nostrum sapiente ipsa! Veniam, laudantium accusantium, odio maxime quo adipisci possimus enim quam, voluptate quidem animi perferendis delectus aliquam?</p>
  </div>
</div>
```